# AWS CodeDeploy deployment not starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Just in the past hour, our AWS CodeDeploy deployments have started hanging before even having a Start Time when looking at the Deployment Details page.  The Status stays at `In Progress` indefinitely.  We have not changed any of our deployment lifecycle details, so that leads me to believe that this is either some kind of CodeDeploy outage, or some kind of fluke that I'm not sure how to reset (Stopping the deployment and starting another ends up in the same place).

Has anyone else experienced this problem?  Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like there is currently degraded performance on the Virginia region EC2 API, I'm also having issues with CodeDeploy not working and I assumed it may be from the increase in error rates on `DescribeInstances` in that region. [AWS status page](http://status.aws.amazon.com/)

Comment: That only seems to have started very recently. I think Andrew is probably having a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check the host agent on your instances. It's possible that it stopped running.

Comment: The codedeploy-agent service was still running on the instance.  I tried restarting it, but the problem hasn't gone away.  I _was_ able to get one build to go through, and another to start before hanging, so it seems to be somewhat intermittent :/

Comment: You'll have to look at the host agent logs then to see what's failing.

Comment: It's filled with a bunch of `2015-12-17 00:49:40 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(24008)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.814757 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"...")` statements, and now I'm getting `Deployment d-94BFTBO0D hasn't completed adding instances. Deployment status: FAILED` errors from CodeDeploy.  It seems like this is related to the degraded performance issue.

Comment: Yea the new error is consistent with current event. Do you have logs from your previous deployments when you were getting the first error?.

Comment: It started working again right as they announced they had fixed it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: For me, it was running on some and not on others, or it was frozen trying to start. This was on newly-spun-up instances, so no idea yet what's gone wrong. As soon as I started the agent on the servers, the codedeploy deployments succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen and I kept restarting the pipeline to no avail.  I finally pushed a minor change and it magically started working again.